# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'columnMode' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-datatable'

Tags: angularjs, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx-datatable with Angular 4.x. I am implementing a table as described [here](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#responsive).
I have got the below error message. Does ngx-datatable have any dependency?

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 
'columnMode' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-datatable'
```

Please let me know your comments on the same.

Thanks,
Raja K

Comment: How do you expect to get some help without any code whatsoever?

Comment: I have specified a reference link. I just use the same code. Will that help?

Comment: Unfortunately No, that doesn't help because that is a working demo and can't find issues in a working piece of code. Have you installed the package using npm? What is your Angular 4.x? Typescript version? To guide you t right place need more info. Answering your question does it have any dependency? Documentation here says no dependencies https://www.npmjs.com/package/@swimlane/ngx-datatable

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post, but this may actually help someone out at some point since I ran across the exact same issue. @kulls you gave the perfect information. Frankly those insensitive comments are uncalled for. This problem is pretty easy to understand without a lot of information provided.

So I happened to be doing the exact same demo you were doing and had the same issue.
The demo provides the import:`import { ColumnMode } from 'projects/swimlane/ngx-datatable/src/public-api';`

But what it really should be is:`import { ColumnMode } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';`

I think it used to be the first path, but they introduced a breaking change at some point. I'm using Angular 9, but my guess is it's the same for 4.